# Call a Linq to SQL user defined function multiple times in one trip to the DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a user defined function that takes 2 datetime parameters and returns a short.

I've added it to my Linq to Sql model, which means I have a function like below:

```
private short? Aqua_NumShopDays(System.Nullable<System.DateTime> start,
                                System.Nullable<System.DateTime> end)
```

So, my question is, how can I call this for multiple date pairs easily (in a LINQy type way) that causes only one trip to the database?

If needed instead of a list of dates, it would still be useful if the first parameter was fixed, and the second parameter was every value in a given range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best I've found so far is to create a table (or user function that creates one) that has a range of numbers, then use that in Linq-To-SQL, as below:

```
// NumberRange is my user defined function, that returns a table with all a row per number
// Here I take that number and calculate the date based on an offset from today
var test = from dayOffset in ARDC.NumberRange(1, 10)
           select DateTime.Today.AddDays(dayOffset.Counter.Value); // Counter is the column name of the table returned

// Using the dates, that are calculated on the server, I select a call to the SQL function
var testResults = from toDate in test
                  select ARDC.Aqua_NumShipDays(DateTime.Today, toDate).Value;

var t = testResults.ToList(); // This results in ONE trip to the database! (yay!)
```